# Share onKeyDown between Preferences and Activity?

Tags: android, inheritance

My App allows users to change what certain hard keys do on it. They can choose what each key does in the app preferences and then on onKeyDown I fire the action selected by the user.

I noticed that many of those who test this functionality, first set a hard key to do something and immediatelly press the key to corroborate if the change is in effect. However as right now the onKeyDown is only on my MainActivity they aren't getting the right feedback.

For this reason I want to reuse the onKeyDown in both my MainActivity and my PreferenceActivity. I tried to extend a BaseActivity but this can't work for both a PreferenceActivity and a regular one. Is there any way to do this through innheritance? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to do this via inheritance since PreferenceActivity inherits from Activity so you'd have to write 2 classes anyway (which defeats the purpose).

You could alternatively use a mapping that transforms a keydown event into one that the user has set.

```
public class DownKeyMapper {

private static Map<Integer, Integer> mKeyCodeMap;

public static void init(Map<Integer, Integer> pKeyMap) {
    // init here with your mappings from preferences
    mKeyCodeMap = pKeyMap;
}

public static void mapKey(int pFromKeyCode, int pToKeyCode) {
    mKeyCodeMap.put(pFromKeyCode, pToKeyCode);
}

public static int getMappedKey(int pKeyCode) {
    if (mKeyCodeMap.containsKey(pKeyCode)) {
        return mKeyCodeMap.get(mKeyCodeMap);
    } else {
        return pKeyCode;
    }
}
}
```

So in your onKeyDown you'd use:

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    keyCode = DownKeyMapper.getMappedKey(keyCode);
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope this helps!